# \today month as text

Tags: datetime

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{.}
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

Prints:

[image]

How can I make it print this:

07 May, 2013

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [the `datetime` manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime), you have two solutions:

- either use the predefined `shortdate` format, which will print "07th may, 2013";
- or define a new date format to get rid of the ordinal as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}

\newdateformat{mydate}{\twodigit{\THEDAY}{ }\shortmonthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}

\begin{document}

\shortdate
\today

\mydate
\today
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I skipped the problem with the ordinal, working on it now.

Comment: Is it possible to customize `\today` format yourself?

Comment: See my edit for both answers. `:)`

Comment: this is the reason why latex is truly an abomination :) terrible!

Answer (score 20):

Here is an humble attempt without having to use any package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\today}{\ifnum\number\day<10 0\fi \number\day \space%
\ifcase \month \or January\or February\or March\or April\or May%
\or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi,%
\number \year} 
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```